# Trying to convert a .tex File into xml with tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, ubuntu

i am trying to use tex4ht to create an xml file for my document written tex to  be read on ebooks and such. My sample file is

```
    \documentclass[ebook,oneside,openany]{memoir}
    \usepackage{tex4ht}
    \usepackage[german]{babel}
     \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
        Some text in English
    \end{document}
```

An error is thrown saying:

(./text_file.xref
Runaway argument?
{\GenericError { }{LaTeX Error: No \begingroup \let \let \d :fn \edef \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before :CrsWrd was complete.

I have been searching the web for hours and still have no clue what is wrong. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and TeX Live 2019/Debian if that matters. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You definitely don't need to include `\usepackage{tex4ht}` in your document. Remove that line and compile your file using `make4ht test_file`. I can compile your example without errors with current TeX Live 2020. One problem is that TeX Live 2019 is quite old, so itt is possible that there were some errors that were fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of that. I will install Texlive 2020 and try again. I was trying to use the tex4ht package so I could see if the code compiled in kile (thats more comfortable for me). When I used the terminal "xhlatex file" it gave me same errors.

Comment: TeX4ht needs to be used in the DVI mode and then some post-processing. I don't know if Kile supports custom compilation tools, but if yes, you may try to add `make4ht`, which is now recommended over `htlatex` and other similar scripts for the TeX4ht compilation.